# Arabic fonts do not work in listboxes and arrays when exporting the application to Android AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on designing a program with two versions, one for Windows and the other for Android, but the font is of the type “Arial” within the Arabic language fonts, it works inside the Listbox and in programming arrays, normally in Windows, and does not work in Android, where the text appears fragmented into letters.
We ask you to help us solve the problem, and thank you very much.

problem example/
I used this code with the Listbox, and it works fine with Windows, but it does not work with Android, where the text appears broken letters

```
  var titleFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
  titleFormat.font = 'Arial';
  titleFormat.size = 20;
  titleFormat.color = 0x008800; 
  list..setStyle("TextFormat", titleFormat);
```

Comment: Try using Arial Unicode font. It has Arabic characters. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I found a solution to this problem which is the jeemExtension library file which contains many codes that work on ActionScript 3 and among those codes is the Arabic script code in ActionScript 3,
I will attach a link explaining the solution to the problem as there is an explanation of the solution to the problem at the end of the video, while the library link is at the bottom of the video.     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH7-mxINjOk